# XHR Get request doesn't load the received HTML string from Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, xmlhttprequest

I am building my first express app.
So far all my requests from the front-end where triggered by anchor elements  for the GET requests and  elements for the POST requests.  All the responses from the server are generated with express function res.render() or res.redirect().

Now I am trying to implement user authentication with json web tokens and localStorage. Once my user is logged in, I generate a token on the back-end side and send it to the front-end like so:

```
 res.render('loggedIn', {token: token});
```

Then I save this token in the localStorage (within a pug template):

```
 const token = !{JSON.stringify(token)};
 window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
```

All good so far, but now I have to send my token back to the back end - From what I have read it is straight forward to do so by including it in the request header. But as my request where only made through anchor element , I now have to make my own "custom" request right ??

So with XMLHttpRequest my code is:

```
function sendGetWithAuth(endUrl) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', endUrl);
        request.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (request.readyState === 4){
                resolve(request.response);
            }
        }
        request.setRequestHeader('x-auth-token', window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
        request.send();
    });
}
```

And instead of using anchor element , I set up a click event listener on my target:

```
target.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const endUrl = '/job/6789'
    sendGetWithAuth(endUrl).then(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }
    )
});
```

When I go back to the browser, click my target the XHR request sends fine, the Headers contain my token, and the response payload contains the HTML send by the res.render(), but nothing happens on the page, I am still on the same page where I clicked my target and have not been redirected to the requested page. The status of the request is: **[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]**

( When my target is a link `<a href='/job/6789'>TARGET </a>`, it works fine (I am redirected to the /job/6789 page. (But no headers are set with the anchor element)).

My first question was: How to load and HTML string response in the browser after and XHR GET request ?

[EDIT 30-10-2020]
My new question is: **How is an XHR GET to and end url different than a link (with anchor tag) to that same end url.**

**Is there a way to place a "custom" request that will redirect to the end url of the request ?**

I have tried adding `window.location = endUrl` after placing the XHR GET request (within the same event handler). It places the XHR GET then redirects me to the endUrl but I loose my token on the way.

(in the browser's console I see the XHR GET endUrl then "Browser navigated to: /endUrl" then another GET endUrl (caused by the redirection I assume but which overrides the headers of my XHR request) so I land on the requested page but without my token.

Comment: `.then( (response) => {  return response; })` Is equivalent to `.then( r => r)`. It does nothing. You are returning the response to nowhere. You need to pass the response to another function.

Comment: You don't need a custom request. Use a cookie. Does this answer your question? [How to store jwt in cookie and pass it to authentication function when redirecting a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524264/how-to-store-jwt-in-cookie-and-pass-it-to-authentication-function-when-redirecti)

Comment: You're just returning the response value to the bit space, do the redirection instead.

Comment: Quick note: `window.localStorage` can be shortened to `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `localStorage` works well for front-end apps, but in your case it might be better to use a cookie. Plant a cookie by calling `res.cookie(<name>, <value>, <options>)` in your expressjs route handler, then install the npm package `cookie-parser`, require it, use it as a middleware in your app, then you can simply use `req.cookies.<name>` in your job route handler. With this approach you can use an anchor that goes directly to that URL.

Comment: Thanks @expressjs123 . 
Indeed this is a good work around my initial need: setting up authentication. 
By using cookies instead of localStorage, I don't need to place custom requests any more and can check the incoming cookies `jwt.verify(req.cookies.token, 'SECRET') `to allow access or not to certain routes! IT WORKS !

->I am still wondering: **How is an XHR GET request to an end url different than an anchor tag to that same end url** 

I guess XHR was created to allow data injection in html pages without having to reload the page, maybe that's why it doesn't redirect to the end url ?